# Turning "Discoverable" on

Tags: android, bluetooth

Does turning "Discoverable" on under Bluetooth setting increase power consumption? When it's switched on, does it constantly put the phone in inquiry scanning? If not constant, how often does it inquiry scan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will drain power - Most devices will allow to be discoverable only for a few minutes / seconds for this reason and also due to privacy reasons. 
The duty cycle of the scan is configurable by the bluetooth stack and by default it scans few milliseconds and rests for a few milliseconds the actual periodicity also depends on if the device is in other connections etc.
Some of the new chips have low power scan which tries to scan for presence of RF activity before doing a full scan.

Comment: Do you know which chips scan for presence of RF first, beside the Bluecore6?

Comment: Most of the leading chips does , TI's cc256x and WiLink series, Broadcom

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=727711

This is a thread all about bluetooth and power drain. From the two minutes I took looking for it, it seems that, as one would logically think, having it on discoverable mode does drain it faster.

How much? I'm sure that you can find that information in that thread.